# $L^2$ convergence + which condition implies pointwise convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^2([0,1])$ which converges to $f$ in $L^2$-norm. Is there an easy condition on the $f_n$, which ensures that $f_n \to f$ pointwise ?

Comment: Continuity. $ $

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi ??? If you mean that $f_n$ and $f$ continuous, $||f_n-f||_2\to0$ implies that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere, that's not so. The standard example of $f_n\to f$ in norm but not almost everywhere can be easily modified to use continuous functions...

Comment: I misread, and meant $f$ continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you know that if $f_n\to f$ in norm then some *subsequence* tends to $f$ almost everywhere. If you look at the proof of that you see that $$\sum||f_{n+1}-f_n||_2<\infty$$implies $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere. (Proof: The condition implies $\left|\left|\sum|f_{n+1}-f_n|\right|\right|_2<\infty$, so $\sum|f_{n+1}-f_n|<\infty$ almost everywhere.)

That's a very strong condition, but it's the only one that springs to mind...